How to setup ssh-agent to persist keys after closing remote connection for use in cron jobs?
I have several cron jobs that require password protected ssh keys. The jobs run each morning and are consistently failing due to the agent not keeping the keys alive after disconnecting from the remote server. This is a server that i've inherited and previously persisted keys, but after a recent update and reboot they no longer persist.
I've tried running the ssh-agent and adding the keys after with
eval `ssh-agent -s`

There is a .config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service which starts the agent at login, then I manually add the keys after, but the keys do not persist after disconnecting.
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

The $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set in .bashrc via
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket

What is the best way to keep these keys in the ssh-agent after disconnecting for use in cron jobs?
Linux Version:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.7 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.7"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.7
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7"


Your eval sets SSH_AUTH_SOCK anew. If you want to use the value from .bashrc then you mustn't evaluate the output of ssh-agent -s on your own.
